# Windows Phone 7.X C# visual studio ads error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, ads

i'm trying to use ads with one my app, but where i try to add the banner visual studio give me that error : http://s9.postimg.org/mq0gxx2wt/screen.jpg

here the full error :

> An Exception was thrown.
>
> ArgumentException: String cannot have zero length.
>
> StackTrace at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.CreateAssemblyName(String
>   assemblyString, Boolean forIntrospection, RuntimeAssembly&
>   assemblyFromResolveEvent)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.AdManager.SetExceptionMessagesCulture()    at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.AdManager..cctor()
>
> InnerException: None

i have not touch anything, just take the ADControl from the toolbox to the design part

anyone know what's that?

thank you

Comment: show the exception relevant code.

Comment: Even if you recompile?

Comment: i don't even compile it, just when i add it i get this error
maybe i haven't explain it well : 
1-i drag the ADControl to the phone in the designer
2-here the phone disappear and the error appear

i have this error even with an empty project

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Visual Studio 2012 with the Advertising SDK. Try use Visual Studio 2010 Express with Windows Phone because there is an issue for AdControl 6.1 which crash VS2012 designer.

Answer (score 0):

Add any property to the AdControl, save it, remove the added property and save again, it should solve the designer crash issue.

Comment: Use XAML directly while adding / removing property.